# Are peapod orders considered supermarket expenses for American Express cashback program?

Tags: american-express, eligible-expenses

I just applied for an AmEx that gives 6% cashback on supermarket purchases, but I buy all my groceries from Peapod. I was just wondering if anyone knows if the peapod expenses are indeed considered supermarket purchases by American Express.

Thanks!

Comment: An excellent card that I also have. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You best bet would be to call Peapod or American Express. I would start with Peapod.

On your CC statement it says what category your payment was in like in the example below.[image]

Comment: I guess you were right Kirill. Even though your answer did not tell me what I needed immediately, I was able to check which Expense Category and Category Code my current Peapod purchases were being categorized in by my bank. Right now I have a Bank of America Card, and even though the Peapod charge specifically lists "GROCERIES" in the charge description that I see on my online banking page, BofA has this on the transaction details:

Merchant Category:  Direct Mark- Other

Expense Category:  Mail Order/Telephone Order Providers

Merchant Category Code:  5969

Comment: So, weird, even though the description says groceries, they are qualifying Peapod as a Direct Mark - Other expense. So I tweeted to @AskAmex to ask them (because I figured they would know more than Peapod in this regard) and they say that the purchase should qualify for their cashback program, and that I should contact them if they were not. That's great from  them.

Comment: @silverCORE +1 for the tweeting the question, didn't know they offered this type of communication. Yes it's very dependent on the provider, since it's all based on their discretion.

Comment: @silverCORE I would also like to note that banks and credit card companies can compromise so contacting them directly and asked them to change "xyz" can sometimes work. In my opinion AMEX is one of the best when it comes to customer service. So if the case was that they didn't offer the discount I would call and bring it up and explain that I felt it should fall into the supermarket category.

Comment: definitely. I had a reply from AmEx less than an hour after I had asked my question. The fact that they asked me to contact them if I had any trouble was nice, I feel the social handles of most banks would just say that it is what it is.

Comment: My BofA card did not list Peapod as Groceries, but I'll try calling them as this would gain me about $18.